# How do I add Counter-Strike (TTT) weapons to Half-Life 2 Base?

Tags: garrys-mod, hammer

I have finally figured out how to use the Hammer Editor. I opened it up and started creating maps on the Half-Life 2 "Base". However, I am making the map for TTT for Garry's Mod, which I presume uses Counter-Strike weapons like the sniper and the shotgun. How do I get Counter-Strike weapons into the Half-Life 2 base map I am working on?

I do not own any Counter-Strike games.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a simple answer... and silly I didn't find it in the first place.

With the ttt.fgd file installed, I got an entity and named it to weapon_zm_(Weapon type). This came up as an error in H.E, and while playing HL2 nothing showed up, but in Gmod it showed up and worked.

[Here is the tutorial I got it from](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QY3q3T1KEL8)

Comment: nice workaround, but that looks pretty buggy to me. Good it works for you, though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not own or have CS games installed you can **not** use their materials, since you just don't have them. You can't generate materials out of thin air.

However, using CS (and other games) related content work pretty much straight forward by just using that game as a configuration template or by creating a new Config for Source SDK as described below.

Please note, that players using your map will be required to own the game(s) you used to make your map or they will get errors at places where (*insert not owned, but used games here*) materials were used or run into other trouble, like game crashes.

Anyway, here is how you do it:

> Choosing a Configuration
>
> By default, Hammer has no "Garry's Mod" configuration. It is possible
>   to create one, but it may not actually be what you are looking for.
>   The "Garry's Mod" configuration features no extra "Valve" content
>   except for what "Half-Life 2" and "Garry's Mod" itself comes with, and
>   any other content will be custom content. This means that if you do
>   not need to use any custom content you have present in your "Garry's
>   Mod" folder, you should use a configuration below instead, so that you
>   gain access to a far larger amount of "Valve" content.
>
> - If you have "The Orange Box", you should use the Half-Life 2: Episode Two configuration. You should use this because it contains the
>     newest "Source" technology and has a huge amount of "Valve" content.
>     It is recommended to use this over any other configuration.
> - If you do not have "The Orange Box", you should use the "Counter-Strike: Source" configuration. You should use this because
>     "Counter-Strike: Source" is owned by a large amount of "Garry's Mod"
>     players and using any of it's content will not be a problem.
> - If you do not have "Counter-Strike: Source", you should use the "Garry's Mod" configuration. You should use this because it is better
>     than using the "Half-Life 2" configuration.
>
> It is possible to copy any "Garry's Mod" content you may have into the
>   "Half-Life 2: Episode Two" game folders so you can use it while using
>   the "Half-Life 2: Episode Two" configuration. The same can be done for
>   "Counter-Strike: Source", and any further content you may want to
>   create a large all-in-one configuration.
>
> If you still decide on using a "Garry's Mod" configuration, perhaps
>   for the purpose of creating an all-in-one configuration, read below.
>
> ---
>
> Creating the Configuration
>
> The "Garry's Mod" configuration must be created on the "Orange Box"
>   half of the "Source SDK". If you create it on the "Episode One" side
>   of the "Source SDK", it will not work properly or at all.
>
> Create new configuration in Hammer, call it "Garry's Mod" (Tools >
>   Options > Edit > Add)
>
> Game Data Files: 
>   (orangebox/bin)
>
> - HalfLife2.fgd = Ep2 (HL2 aswell)
> - base.fgd
> - cstrike.fgd = CS:S
> - dod.fgd = DoD:S
> - hl2mp.fgd = HL2:DM (could be needed)
> - portal.fgd = Portal
> - tf.fgd = TF2 
>     *(garrysmod/garrysmod) Garrysmod.fgd (OPTIONAL)
>
> Default Point Entity class: info_player_start
>   Default SolidEntity class: func_detail
>   Cordon Texture: tools/toolsskybox
>   Game Executable Directory: $SteamUserDir\garrysmod
>   Game Directory: $SteamUserDir\garrysmod\garrysmod
>   Hammer VMF Directory: (VMF saves for Garrysmod) (Choose a place like $SteamUserDir\garrysmod\garrysmod\maps\vmf)
>
> Now go to the last Tab, Build programs..
>
> Game Executable: $SteamUserDir\garrysmod\hl2.exe
>   BSP $SteamUserDir\sourcesdk\bin\orangebox\bin\vbsp.exe
>   VIS $SteamUserDir\sourcesdk\bin\orangebox\bin\vvis.exe
>   RAD $SteamUserDir\sourcesdk\bin\orangebox\bin\vrad.exe
>   Place compiled maps... $SteamUserDir\garrysmod\garrysmod\maps
>
> It will say that the changes will show when you open Hammer another
>   time but you need to restart the Source SDK as well in order you use your new config.

(c) http://wiki.garrysmod.com

Comment: I guess what I asked was pretty silly (trying to get items from nowhere). From what I gathered above, it sounds like you can get items (models/textures etc) from one game and copy them to another, to work with them in the Hammer Editor. How does one do this? Would it also be possible to in H.E, say if I wanted a model that doesn't exist in the HL2 location, leave a model URL for a model location on another computer on something like prop_static?

Comment: You can get those items in Hammer, but they would still not work properly when playing the map without the game they came from.